# Implementing Multi-threading/Parallel processing in script

Tags: multithreading, powershell, copy-paste

So I have this simple script that allows me to copy and paste items in a different folder while also changing their name in Windows Powershell.

```
$destfolder = '.\destfolder\'
get-childitem -Recurse -File .\srcfolder\ | Foreach-Object {
    $newname = $_.name
$newname = $_.directory.parent.name + '-' + $_.directory.name + '-' + $_.name
Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination (Join-Path $destfolder $newname) -Verbose
}
```

I'm wondering how to add multi-threading/parallel processing to make it go faster. And maybe robocopy.

I tried to use the object parallel feature but it didn't work.

-I checked and it seems like the reason why Foreach-Object -Parallel didn't work is cause I'm running powershell version 5.1.22621.608

-I want to copy files from multiple subdirectories in a folder at once into a single folder without the directories, however robocopy doesn't allow for this

Comment: Have you compared the speed it's using the disk drive to the maximum speed the disk drive can work at?

Comment: ^^ good question. I would expect parallel write operations on a disk drive to be slower than single-threaded, especially due to the movement of the write head in a spinning drive, but also due to fragmentation in a solid state drive. Parallelism sees a performance benefit when there is a wait state like a network client would have, or when there are multiple resources to process parallel requests like a CPU with multiple cores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can **speed up your command even in a single thread**, by directly piping to [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item) in combination with a [delay-bind script block](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters):

```bash
$destfolder = '.\destfolder\'
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File .\srcfolder\ | 
  Copy-Item -Destination { 
    Join-Path $destfolder ($_.directory.parent.name, $_.directory.name, $_.name -join '-') 
  } -Verbose -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

---

As for **parallelism**:

*Windows PowerShell* (as opposed to [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)) has only *child-process*-based parallelism built in, via [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job), which is both resource-intensive and slow.

However, the **install-on-demand third-party `Invoke-Parallel` function** that comes as part of the [`PSParallelPipeline` module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSParallelPipeline) offers ***thread*-based parallelism with pipeline support**, similar to `ForEach-Object -Parallel` in PowerShell (Core) 7+.

You'll have to test yourself whether its use results in any performance improvement in your case, but here's how you would invoke it:

First, install the module:

```bash
# Install the module that has the Invoke-Parallel function.
# (Only needed once).
Install-Module PSParallelPipeline -Scope CurrentUser
```

Then use [`Invoke-Parallel`](https://github.com/santisq/PSParallelPipeline) to process up to 5 input files in parallel (you can modify this number with `-ThrottleLimit`):

```bash
$destfolder = '.\destfolder\'
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File .\srcfolder\ |
  Invoke-Parallel {
    $_ | Copy-Item -Destination (
      Join-Path $using:destfolder ($_.directory.parent.name, $_.directory.name, $_.name -join '-') 
    ) -Verbose -WhatIf
  }
```